# Speed of Layer Rendering and Visibility in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, performance

This map is a combination of several layers: http://arcg.is/2fTGANA

When I share this out with others they experience difficulty in rendering when they log in to AGOL as compared to when they do not.  What could be causing this?

Also, even though I adjust the visibility on the raster layer it does not necessarily display correctly.

Comment: Sounds like an [ESRI support](http://support.esri.com/) question...

Comment: @SteveC I've checked out the map both logged in and out and experienced similar results in rendering. Any specifics about how the rendering performs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a lot better than when I last checked your link a few days back.

IMO you are trying to render too many complex geoms at once.  I would strongly consider:

1. Creating tile packages for the 2012 Presidential Election Results and USA Black Population layers in ArcGIS Desktop.
2. Publish these to AGO.
3. Simplify the same layers significantly and use integrate tool in ArcGIS Desktop to clean any gaps.
4. Publish as a hosted feature service
5. Use this hosted feature service as the popup for the tile services

[image]

This should be lightning fast.

In short the rendering is taking awhile as you are pulling a large # of geoms from the service.  The alternative is to play with your layer scale level ranges to perhaps switch between state/county/tract to load less geoms for each scale level.